# List within a Dictionary confusion

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

So I have a list within a dictionary, I reference the Key to receive the list data. But how do I

a. Prevent the return being within `('')`.

b. reference on the second item in the list (In my example below the second list item being my the numbers rather than the labels).

```
irTable = {"a1" : ("lamp", 16273), 
           "a2" : ("tv", 95724), 
           "b1" : ("lamp2", 857394), 
           "b2" : ("tv2", 48839)
          }

print(irTable["a1"])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? The idea being I call the key to identify the list that has the name and frequency for my pi to IR Blast. E.g. I call a1 > It's the lamp > IR Freq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label, number = irTable["al"]
print("It's the {}".format(label))
```

Will unpack the respective items for you. Please note, the values in the above dictionary are *tuples*, not *lists* which actually carries significance in python.

Comment: That worked a dream, thanks! Apologies, i'm still fairly new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_dict
{'a1': ('lamp', 16273), 'a2': ('tv', 95724), 'b1': ('lamp2', 857394), 'b2': ('tv2', 48839)}
>>> my_dict.keys()            # give you all keys
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2']        
>>> my_dict.values()          # give you all values
[('lamp', 16273), ('tv', 95724), ('lamp2', 857394), ('tv2', 48839)]
>>> my_dict['a1']        # give you value of key a1
('lamp', 16273)
>>> my_dict['a1'][0]     #using index you can get the value
'lamp'
>>> my_dict['a1'][1]
16273
```

Comment: I'll give this a try too. Cheers!